# How to use Joins followed by left outer join in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following database schema structure:

```
School
has_many :students

Students
has_many :books

Books
(has an attribute pages(integer))
```

The issue is I want a total of all the pages of a book a student has at the school level. But there is also a possibility that a student might not have any book.

I want to select the following rails query using ruby code and methods like joins and includes:

```
SELECT * FROM school INNER JOIN students ON students.school_id = schools.id LEFT OUTER JOIN books ON books.student_id = students.id
```

I have tried the following:

```
School.joins({:students => :books}).all
```

But this will not take into account those students who do not have any books. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your ancient version of Ruby on Rails doesn't support `left_outer_joins`. But you can still define joins manually with the string syntax, like this:

```
School
  .joins(:students) # defaults to INNER JOIN
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN books ON books.student_id = students.id')
  .all
```

Btw. you are on an out-dated and unmaintained version of Ruby on Rails. Rails `4.1.6` reached end-of-life about 7 years ago and has a couple of [well-known security vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-12043/product_id-22569/version_id-531031/Rubyonrails-Rails-4.1.6.html). I highly recommend upgrading your application to an up-to-date version of Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
School.left_outer_joins(students: :books).all
```

Comment: I tried. It throws error saying *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `left_outer_joins' for #<Class:0x007f74d2ad5810>.

A bit weird this. Joins works but this does not. I am using rails 4.1.6 btw

Answer (score 0):

you can use Left Joins as follow

```rb
  School.all.left_joins(students: :books)

  the out query is 

  SELECT "schools".* FROM "schools" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "student" ON "student"."school_id" = "schools"."id" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "books" ON "books"."student_id" = "student"."id"
```